# Node ram usage keep increasing

Tags: node.js

I have a page build by node and receive 15 requests/second.

And my function is like this:

```
var somepage = function(req,res){
    res.send(200);
    call_mongo_to_save_some_data(req.somedata); 
}

var call_mongo_to_save_some_data = function(data){
    var needToSave = {}
    needToSave.val1 = data.val1;
    needToSave.val2 = data.val2;
    needToSave.val3 = data.val3;
    needToSave.val4 = data.val4;
    needToSave.val5 = data.val5;

    var db = mongoskin();
    db.collection.insert(needToSave).success(function(){
        db.close();
    }).fail(function(err){ throw err; });
}
```

So you can see I do something after I send the response. To do this, is because I want to reduce the response time. So the client user won't waiting for I save something in mongo.

But after I launch the page, I found that the ram usage is keep increasing. I did some research, saying the res.write clear the output buffer. And compare with my code, I do something after the res.write (res.send). So not sure is that the reason. Or it's some other issue here.

Comment: `call_mongo_to_save_some_data` could be causing memory leak. Can you show what is it?

Comment: `call_mongo_to_save_some_data` is added.

Comment: How did you verify the memory usage? I'd suggest do not close the connection as you are getting 15 req/sec. You can open the connection outside the router and use it throughout. See if it helps.